# Invalid parameter number error for a simple select statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, parameters

I'm getting this error for a relatively simple select statement that usually works for me:

Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' for select statement.

Here's the SQL statements:

```
$thing= connecting::query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE thing1=:thingOne AND random!=: ran_dom AND thing2=:thingTwo AND thing3=:thingThree AND thing4=:thingFour AND thing5=:thingFive AND thing6=:thingSix',                      array(':thingOne'=>$thingOne),array(':ran_dom'=>$ran_dom),array(':thingTwo'=>$thingTwo),array(':thingThree'=>$thingThree),array(':thingFour'=>$thingFour),array(':thingFive'=>$thingFive),array(':thingSix'=>$thingSix));

$thing= connecting::query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE thing1=:thingOne AND random!=: ran_dom',                     array(':thingOne'=>$thingOne),array(':ran_dom'=>$ran_dom));
```

Both of these don't work, my syntax is correct, it's formatted properly, and I've counted the number of parameters and it does match the number of tokens.

For some reason whenever my queries contain more than one parameter this error comes up. For example, if I just queried for the "$thingOne" variable the statement would execute.

I know there's got to be something simple I'm missing, I just can't spot it.

Comment: i don't know how that `::query` method works, but if this is pdo wrapepd, normally what you do is declare key pairs, not array batches, `[':placeholder1' => $value1, ':placeholder2' => $value2]`, not `[':placeholder1' => $value1], [':placeholder2' => $value2]` like what is stated above

Comment: it's fine here's my query method:

Comment: public static function query($query,$params = array())
 {
  

  $statement = self :: db()->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute($params);
  if(explode(' ',$query)[0] == 'SELECT')
  {
   $data = $statement->fetchAll();
   return $data;
  }

 }

Comment: It's not fine. You're passing a bunch of arrays, each of which has a single value in them, instead of a single array with a bunch of values in it. This is why there's a mismatch.

Comment: okay I'll fix it